# Need help with solidity?

Tags: solidity, web3js, pancakeswap

Hello everyone so Im building flashswap arbitrage program and I got stuck and cant figure out why maybe anyone has a solution :
this is the code I have for solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.6.6;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

// uniswap and library impoerts

// Uniswap interface and library imports
import "./libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol";
import "./libraries/SafeERC20.sol";
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol";
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import "./interfaces/IERC20.sol";

contract PancakeFlashSwap {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    // Factory and Routing addresses
    address private constant PANCAKE_FACTORY =
        0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73;
    address private constant PANCAKE_ROUTER =
        0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E;

    // Token Addresses // WBTC // WETH // EGLD // GMT //
    address private constant WBNB = 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c;
    address private constant BUSD = 0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56;
    address private constant CAKE = 0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82;
    address private constant BTCB = 0x7130d2A12B9BCbFAe4f2634d864A1Ee1Ce3Ead9c;
    address private constant CROX = 0x2c094F5A7D1146BB93850f629501eB749f6Ed491;

    // Trade Variables
    uint256 private deadline = block.timestamp + 1 days;
    uint256 private constant MAX_INT =
        115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935;

    // Fund Contract
    // Provides a function for contract to be funded
    function fundFlashLoanContract(
        address _owner,
        address _token,
        uint256 _amount
    ) public {
        IERC20(_token).transferFrom(_owner, address(this), _amount);
    }

    // Get Contract balance

    function GetBalanceOfToken(address _address) public view returns (uint256) {
        return IERC20(_address).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    // Initiate Arbitrage
    // Begins recieving loan and performs arbitrage

    function StartArbitrage(address _tokenToBorrow, uint256 _amount) external {
        // Every token that has been added to contract must be initialized here as well
        IERC20(WBNB).safeApprove(address(PANCAKE_ROUTER), MAX_INT);
        IERC20(BUSD).safeApprove(address(PANCAKE_ROUTER), MAX_INT);
        IERC20(CAKE).safeApprove(address(PANCAKE_ROUTER), MAX_INT);
        IERC20(BTCB).safeApprove(address(PANCAKE_ROUTER), MAX_INT);
        IERC20(CROX).safeApprove(address(PANCAKE_ROUTER), MAX_INT);

        // Get the factory pair address for buying tokens
        address pair = IUniswapV2Factory(PANCAKE_FACTORY).getPair(
            _tokenToBorrow,
            WBNB
        );

        // Return error if token pair combination does not exist
        require(pair != address(0), "Pool Does not exist");

        // Figure out which token is (0 or 1) has the amount and assign
        address token0 = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).token0();
        address token1 = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).token1();
        uint amount0Out = _tokenToBorrow == token0 ? _amount : 0;
        uint amount1Out = _tokenToBorrow == token1 ? _amount : 0;

        // Passing flashloan data for "swap" function to execute
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(_tokenToBorrow, _amount);

        // Execute initial swap to run flashloan
        IUniswapV2Pair(pair).swap(
            amount0Out,
            amount1Out,
            address(this),
            data
        );
    }

    function PancakeCall(
        address _sender,
        uint256 _amount0,
        uint256 _amount1,
        bytes calldata _data
    ) external {
        // Make sure that request is coming from this contract
        address token0 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token0();
        address token1 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token1();
        address pair = IUniswapV2Factory(PANCAKE_FACTORY).getPair(
            token0,
            token1
        );
        require(
            msg.sender == pair,
            "Uncorrect sender!!! Sender needs to match pair"
        );
        require(
            _sender == address(this),
            "Uncorrect sender!!! Sender needs to match contract"
        );
        // Decode the data to calculate repayment
        (address tokenToBorrow, uint256 amount) = abi.decode(
            _data,
            (address, uint256)
        );
        // Calculete amount to pay back to flashloan
        uint256 fee = ((amount * 3) / 997) + 1;
        //
        // This must be used to calculate if we will have profit
        //
        uint256 amountToRepay = amount + fee;

        // Do Arbitrage
        // !!!!!!!!!

        // Withdraw the profit
        // !!!!!!!!!

        // Pay loan back
        IERC20(tokenToBorrow).transfer(pair, amountToRepay);
    }
}
```

this is the code I have for testing :

```
const { ethers, waffle } = require("hardhat");
const { expect, assert } = require("chai");
const { impersonateFundErc20 } = require("../utils/utilities");

const {
  abi,
} = require("../artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol/IERC20.json");
const provider = waffle.provider;

describe("FlashSwap Contract", () => {
  let FLASHSWAP,
    BORROW_AMOUNT,
    FUND_AMOUNT,
    initiateFundHuman,
    txArbitrage,
    gasUsedUSD;

  const DECIMALS = 18;

  const BUSD_WHALE = "0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec";
  const BUSD = "0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56";
  const WBNB = "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c";
  const CAKE = "0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82";
  const BTCB = "0x7130d2A12B9BCbFAe4f2634d864A1Ee1Ce3Ead9c";
  const CROX = "0x2c094F5A7D1146BB93850f629501eB749f6Ed491";
  // This has to be changed
  BASE_TOKEN_ADDRESS = BUSD;
  const tokenBase = new ethers.Contract(BASE_TOKEN_ADDRESS, abi, provider);
  beforeEach(async () => {
    // Get the owner as the signer
    [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

    // Ensure that whale has balance
    const whale_balance = await provider.getBalance(BUSD_WHALE);
    expect(whale_balance).not.equal("0");

    //Deploy our smartContract
    const FlashSwap = await ethers.getContractFactory("PancakeFlashSwap");
    FLASHSWAP = await FlashSwap.deploy();
    await FLASHSWAP.deployed();

    // Configure borrowing
    const borrowAmountHuman = "1";
    BORROW_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseUnits(borrowAmountHuman, DECIMALS);

    // you dont need this in real world
    // Configure Funding -THIS IS ONLY FOR TESTING
    initiateFundHuman = "100";
    FUND_AMOUNT = BORROW_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseUnits(
      initiateFundHuman,
      DECIMALS
    );

    // Fund contract - ONLY FOR TESTING
    await impersonateFundErc20(
      tokenBase,
      BUSD_WHALE,
      FLASHSWAP.address,
      initiateFundHuman
    );
  });

  describe("Arbitrage Execution", () => {
    it("ensures the contract is funded", async () => {
      const flashSwapBalance = await FLASHSWAP.GetBalanceOfToken(
        BASE_TOKEN_ADDRESS
      );

      const flashSwapBalanceHuman = ethers.utils.formatUnits(
        flashSwapBalance,
        DECIMALS
      );

      console.log(flashSwapBalanceHuman);

      expect(Number(flashSwapBalanceHuman)).equal(Number(initiateFundHuman));
    });

    it("Execute arbitrage", async () => {
      console.log(FLASHSWAP.StartArbitrage());
      txArbitrage = await FLASHSWAP.StartArbitrage(
        BASE_TOKEN_ADDRESS,
        BORROW_AMOUNT
      );
      assert(txArbitrage);

      // Print balance
      const contractBalance = await FLASHSWAP.GetBalanceOfToken(BUSD);
    });
  });
});
```

and this is the error Im getting :

```
     Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function
    at PancakeFlashSwap.<unrecognized-selector> (contracts/FlashSwap.sol:17)
    at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x58f876857a02d6762e0101bb5c46a8c1ed44dc16)
    at PancakeFlashSwap.StartArbitrage (contracts/FlashSwap.sol:84)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1815:23)
    at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:504:16)
    at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1522:18)
    at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:118:18)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

im using testnet as a network to connect to provider
I thought that is the problem but its not everything runs except StartArbitrage function please help !!!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue, or comment if you need any further help...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this line is causing the error:

```js
    console.log(FLASHSWAP.StartArbitrage());
```

Because `StartArbitrage()` without arguments is not valid...